# click update request button on authentication page in postman using pre-request script?

Tags: postman

while i am running collection on postman than authentication fail is showing but manually one by one request is running proper after hitting update request on authentication page.i want pre-request script to hit update request button on authentication page .If anybody have idea please do share

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a pre-request script, try ticking (or clearing?) the "**Save helper data to request**" checkbox for each request in your collection. Screenshots and vague mentions of this feature are available at https://www.getpostman.com/docs/postman/sending_api_requests/authorization.